# Polymer sending file and other data at the same time with core ajax

Tags: asp.net, polymer

I'm trying to send an image and some more information to the server form the font-end using core-ajax.
And I was wondering about how it cloud be done with one core-ajax element,and how to receive the data in the server (Asp.net) api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FormData object. Mozilla Developer network has a very nice tutorial on [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects). 
You can handle this data at server, just as you handle any other POST request.